Golang Http Request With Certificate
I'm trying to do HTTP request with OpenSSL X509 Keypair,
from the server side it's keep we always get forbidden ( 403 ) response,
this is my code
var pemFile string = "/etc/files/cert/pemFile.pem"
var keyFile string = "/etc/files/cert/keyFile.key"
type loggingTransport struct {
    Transport http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *loggingTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {

    resp, err := t.Transport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }


    if req.TLS != nil {
        // Print client certificate subject DN
        for _, cert := range req.TLS.PeerCertificates {
            fmt.Println("Client Certificate Subject DN:", cert.Subject)
        }
    }
    return resp,err
}

func main() {
    // Load client certificate and key
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(pemFile, keyFile)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error loading client certificate and key: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Set up the TLS config with the client certificate and CA pool
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    transport := &loggingTransport{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
        },
    }

    // Create a custom HTTP client with the transport
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
        Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
    }

    // Prepare the request data
    requestData := map[string]string{
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    }
    requestDataJSON, err := json.Marshal(requestData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error marshalling request data: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Create the HTTP request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://uat.partner.com:8888/access-token", strings.NewReader(string(requestDataJSON)))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating request: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    // Set headers
    req.Header.Set("X-TIMESTAMP", "2024-07-30T11:21:35+07:00")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    // Send the request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error sending request: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read the response
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading response: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Response:", string(body))
}

I tried to print the req object TSL with Roundtripper, but the TLS object is nil.
I'm not sure if is it expected to be nil or not.
and then i also tried to do use curl instead of code ( golang ) and it success,
this is the curl command that i execute
curl --key keyFile.key -E pemFile.pem 'https://uat.partner.com:8888/access-token' --header 'X-TIMESTAMP: 2024-07-30T11:21:35+07:00' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}'

please help to what i missed on my golang side to do the HTTP request using the same certificate as the curl command.
Thank You

A client RoundTrip does not modify the Request object. What is the error? What does the server report for the connection?

i'm not trying to modify the request with roundtripper, I just trying to print the TLS property from req object.
i'm unable to check directly to the server, but they say the request comes from Golang not bringing the required certificate.

I mean that RoundTrip is documented that it does not change a client Request object, and the TLS field is documented as This field is ignored by the HTTP client., so there will be nothing about the connection stored there.

Hmm ok, if we ignore the roundtrip, do I miss something with the client configuration to do the request?
i mean it works if I use curl command.

Your code should be sending a cert, so it's hard to diagnose without more information. Running the client should send the cert, and testing locally shows both curl and go sending the same data.

is there anything that I can do to find the difference between the curl command and my code?
because their argument is always " if it works with curl then the problem should be on your app side, not from server or certificate fault "
oh and even it works with Postman,
ahahah, so I just don't understand why it doesn't works on my code.

Hi @JimB is there any way to prove that my HTTP request already sent certificate ?

A client cert can only be requested by the server (you can't blindly send one), and I don't think the client has a way to log if one was requested and sent. You could trace the handshake with wireshark.

I wonder if the TLS bit is a red herring and it's for example the user-agent header. curl will probably set a user-agent which is well-known and accepted by the server, I wonder what the Go HTTP client is sending. A HTTP 403 can happen for any number of reasons, the TLS part is simply the most scary one in your code and so an easy one to blame for problems :)

Already Check with wireshark and i found the difference between request from curl and from Go HTTP Client,
from curl request it has my certificate name in Certificate Info
but in Go HTTP doesn't have my certificate name in Certificate info

Hi @Gimby i already tried everything,
even i tried to use the same Header from curl,
I check with curl verbose, and I copy every header from curl verbose,
and it still not working,

It is mutal tls authentication right, otherwise this would not make sense. Whats the common Trust? Could it be that the root ca, or issuer cert is available to curl because its in OS cert store but not available to golang!? Root Ca could be added to tls config. With wireshark there should be a tls Handshake with an Alert in it when the handshake fails, whats the Alert Message ?

Ok,
found the issue i think this is the root cause https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23924#issuecomment-367472052 , tried to override the GetClientCertificate and it's done.

OK But you should worry about "that the Certificate Request applies constraints (RSA vs ECDSA, or a specific issuer) which are not satisfied by your certificate" did you found whats wrong with your cert Setup?
